How to Capture and Handle Zero-Length TCP ACK Packets in Go?
I am working on a TCP file streaming server written in Go that communicates with an ESP32 microcontroller. The ESP32 sends TCP packets, including ACK packets with zero-length bodies but containing crucial information in their headers.
My problem is that I cannot correctly capture and handle these zero-length TCP ACK packets. The ACK packets are important for managing the streaming process and ensuring data integrity. Here's a breakdown of my setup:
Go TCP Server:

Listens for incoming connections.
Streams files to the client (ESP32).
Needs to correctly handle ACK packets to manage flow control.

ESP32 Client:

Connects to the Go server.
Receives file data.
Sends ACK packets with zero-length bodies but necessary information in the TCP headers.

Issue:

The server reads data from the connection but fails to capture or correctly interpret the zero-length TCP ACK packets.
doesn't matter whether I use a regular connection reader or a Bufio reader. The problem always remains the same: packets with a length greater than 0 are processed without any issues.

Here is the source code:
package handlers

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "strings"
    "time"

    "source/config"
    "source/models"
    "source/utils"
)

const (
    // (Старый метод) Параметры скейла окна
    // initialWindowSize = 80  // начальный размер окна в байтах
    // maxWindowSize     = 500 // максимальный размер окна в байтах
    ackTimeout    = 3 * time.Second
    chunkSize     = 2000
    maxBufferSize = 1024 * 30
)

type StreamHandler struct {
    config config.Config
}

func NewStreamHandler(config config.Config) *StreamHandler {
    return &StreamHandler{config: config}
}

func (h *StreamHandler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    log.Println(utils.LogFileStreaming)

    request := new(models.Request)
    if err := request.Deserialize(r.Body); err != nil {
        utils.SendErrorMsgAndLog(w, http.StatusBadRequest, utils.MergeMessages(utils.ErrBadRequest, err.Error()))
        return
    }

    fileType := request.Data.FileType
    filesDir, err := h.config.GetFilesDir(fileType)
    if err != nil {
        utils.SendError(w, http.StatusBadRequest, utils.MergeMessages(utils.ErrInvalidFileType, fileType))
        return
    }

    var streamParams models.StreamHandlerParams
    if err := streamParams.Deserialize(request.Data.Params); err != nil {
        utils.SendErrorMsgAndLog(w, http.StatusBadRequest, utils.MergeMessages(utils.ErrBadRequest, err.Error()))
        return
    }

    files, err := os.ReadDir(filesDir)
    if err != nil {
        utils.SendError(w, http.StatusInternalServerError, utils.ErrReadDir)
        return
    }

    var filePath string
    for _, file := range files {
        if !file.IsDir() && strings.TrimSuffix(file.Name(), filepath.Ext(file.Name())) == streamParams.FileName {
            filePath = filepath.Join(filesDir, file.Name())
            break
        }
    }

    if filePath == "" {
        utils.SendError(w, http.StatusNotFound, utils.MergeMessages(utils.ErrFilesNotFound, streamParams.FileName))
        return
    }

    file, err := os.Open(filePath)
    if err != nil {
        utils.SendError(w, http.StatusUnprocessableEntity, utils.MergeMessages(utils.ErrOpenEffect, streamParams.FileName))
        return
    }
    defer file.Close()

    w.Header().Set("Content-Disposition", fmt.Sprintf("attachment; filename=%s.effect", streamParams.FileName))
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream")
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    flusher, ok := w.(http.Flusher)
    if !ok {
        utils.SendError(w, http.StatusInternalServerError, "Streaming not supported")
        return
    }

    log.Println(utils.MergeMessages(utils.LogFileStreamed, streamParams.FileName))

    buffer := make([]byte, chunkSize)
    reader := bufio.NewReader(r.Body)

    for {
        n, err := file.Read(buffer)
        if err != nil && err != io.EOF {
            utils.SendError(w, http.StatusInternalServerError, utils.ErrStreaming)
            return
        }

        if n == 0 {
            break
        }

        if _, err := w.Write(buffer[:n]); err != nil {
            utils.SendError(w, http.StatusInternalServerError, utils.ErrStreaming)
            return
        }

        flusher.Flush()

        if !waitForAck(reader) {
            log.Println("ACK не был получен, поток остановлен")
            return
        }
    }

    log.Println(utils.MergeMessages(utils.LogFileStreamed, streamParams.FileName))
}

func waitForAck(reader *bufio.Reader) bool {
    ackChan := make(chan bool, 1)

    go func() {
        response, err := reader.ReadString('\n')
        if err != nil {
            ackChan <- false
            return
        }
        if strings.Contains(response, "ACK") {
            ackChan <- true
        } else {
            ackChan <- false
        }
    }()

    select {
    case ack := <-ackChan:
        return ack
    case <-time.After(ackTimeout):
        return false
    }
}


It looks like the application is trying to use the HTTP connection in full duplex mode.  If so, enable full duplex.

"... zero-length TCP ACK packets. The ACK packets are important for managing the streaming process and ensuring data integrity" - to me this sounds either like a severely broken protocol (violation of abstraction layers: application layer should not need to interact with transport layer), an attempt to let you Go program directly interact with TCP flow control instead of let the OS do it (bad idea) or a wrong description of what is actually done by the peer. The design of your code especially waitForAck suggests the latter: not "empty" TCP Ack but non-empty application layer payload "ACK".

Also not that the application layer abstraction of TCP is a bidirectional bytestream - it is not visible how the data were actually packetized at the transport layer (TCP) and it should also not matter.
